# How place the Logo over the content? (Z-Index is ignored)

Tags: html, z-index

how can i change the CSS code, to make the Logo (#logo) in the left corner appear OVER all the other divs? A high z-index value doesn't change the position :/ For example, when you click on "Salon" and scroll, the picture and texts scroll over the logo, not beneath.

Here's the link:
http://hosting2022.esy.es/

```
/* HEADER WITH LOGO */

header {        
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index:2000;
    height: 80px;
}

#header-wrapper {
    width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index:9999;
    height:80px;
    line-height:80px;
    position:relative;      
}

#logo {
    margin:20px 0;
    height:40px;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
}

/* MAIN DIV WITH MENU AND CONTENT-DIV*/

#mainx {
  padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
 margin: 0 !important;
 border: 0 !important;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 11000;
}

/* THE MENU DIV */

#menuxx {
    line-height:50%;
    z-index:21000;
    top:35px;
    right:105px;
    width:450px;
    height:70px;
    position:fixed;
    }

/*CONTENT DIV -> Should be placed under the logo and menu*/

#Salon {
top:0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code in your question

Comment: what you mean to say can you please explain.?

Comment: I hope the code snippet helps. The logo of the website should always be at the top of all divs.

Answer (score 1):

Add this css to your style

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your styles (decreased z-index on .mainx)

```
.mainx {
    z-index: 2500;
}
```

Your current solution will not work since you assigned:

```
#logo {
    z-index: 3000;
}
```

and

```
.mainx {
    z-index: 11000;
}
```

Comment: But unfortunately, the menu is not clickable after that. Can you tell me, what do i have to change?

Comment: Add z-index: 3000 on .menuxx

Comment: No, when i add "z-index: 3000" to .menuxx, The content div is displayed over the logo AND the menu. So, the menu isn't clickable again.

Comment: Try: #Team, #Salon, #Produkte, #Preise, #Kontakt, #Impressum { z-index: 2500; }

Answer (score 0):

The the *z-index* being applied to your *#logo* element will not work because it is supposed to have a position of either *relative*, *fixed* or *absolute* position.

Comment: Ok, and why does it still not change, when i add "position: relative" for example to the Logo div?

Comment: The _z-index_ of some other elements are probably higher than that of your _logo_, therefore your logo still remains below other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add style to your `<header>` tag

```
<header style="z-index: 100;">
```

This is how it looks after..

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, when i do this, the menu is not clickable anymore :/